# Template function to extract value out of several nested unordered_map's

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates

Let's assume I have a nested `std::unordered_map` that looks like this:

```
std::unordered_map<ResourceName, std::unordered_map<HAL::ResourceFormat::Color, HAL::RTDescriptor>>
```

I want a function that will return a pointer to `HAL::RTDescriptor` based on two keys `ResourceName` and `HAL::ResourceFormat::Color` if object is present or `nullptr` otherwise. The straightforward implementation looks like this:

```
const HAL::RTDescriptor* ResourceDescriptorStorage::GetRTDescriptor(ResourceName resourceName, HAL::ResourceFormat::Color format) const
    {
        auto mapIt = mRTDescriptorMap.find(resourceName);

        if (mapIt == mRTDescriptorMap.end()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        auto& nestedMap = mapIt->second;
        auto nestedMapIt = nestedMap.find(format);

        if (nestedMapIt == nestedMap.end()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return &nestedMapIt->second;
    }
```

Is there a way to use templates to generalize the logic?
Something with parameter packs for keys. Something that will go through each nested container, check for object availability and return it or `nullptr` at the end:

```
template<
        template<class...> class AssociativeContainer,
        class... Keys
    >
        decltype(auto) Find(const AssociativeContainer<...>& rootContainer, Keys&&... keys)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simpler solution (requires C++17):

```
template<class AssociativeContainer, class Key, class... Keys>
auto Find(const AssociativeContainer& container, Key&& key, Keys&&... keys){
    auto it = container.find(std::forward<Key>(key));
    bool found = it != container.end();
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Keys) == 0)
        return found ? &it->second : nullptr;
    else
        return found ? Find(it->second, std::forward<Keys>(keys)...) : nullptr;
}
```

This also allows to get a reference to any inbetween container, as it doesn't require to pass all keys.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to use templates to generalize the logic? Something with parameter packs for keys. Something that will go through each nested container, check for object availability and return it or nullptr at the end:

Require a little of work (maybe someone more expert than me can make it simpler) but sure it's possible.

By example... given a custom type traits (and `using` to simplify the use) as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct lastType
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename K, typename V>
struct lastType<C<K, V>> : public lastType<V>
 { };

template <typename T>
using lastType_t = typename lastType<T>::type;
```

you can write `Find()` recursively as follows

```
// ground case
template <typename V>
V const * Find (V const & val)
 { return &val; }

// recursion case
template <typename C, typename K0, typename ... Ks>
lastType_t<C> const * Find (C const & cnt, K0 && key0, Ks && ... keys)
 {
   auto mapIt = cnt.find(std::forward<K0>(key0));

   if ( mapIt == cnt.cend() ) 
      return nullptr;

   return Find(mapIt->second, std::forward<Ks>(keys)...);
 }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename T>
struct lastType
 { using type = T; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename K, typename V>
struct lastType<C<K, V>> : public lastType<V>
 { };

template <typename T>
using lastType_t = typename lastType<T>::type;

template <typename V>
V const * Find (V const & val)
 { return &val; }

template <typename C, typename K0, typename ... Ks>
lastType_t<C> const * Find (C const & cnt, K0 && key0, Ks && ... keys)
 {
   auto mapIt = cnt.find(std::forward<K0>(key0));

   if ( mapIt == cnt.cend() ) 
      return nullptr;

   return Find(mapIt->second, std::forward<Ks>(keys)...);
 }

using typeC = std::map<int,
                 std::unordered_map<std::string,
                    std::unordered_map<long,
                       std::map<char, long long>>>>;

int main ()
 {
   typeC c;

   c[0]["one"][2l]['3'] = 4ll;

   auto v = Find(c, 0, "one", 2l, '3');

   std::cout << (*v) << std::endl;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(v), long long const *>, "!" );
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

I'm particularly dumb today: as highlighted by krisz in his answer (thanks), the ternary operator permit the use of `auto` as return type (from C++14).

So there is no needs of the `lastType` custom type traits and `Find()` can be simply written as

```
// ground case
template <typename V>
V const * Find (V const & val)
 { return &val; }

// recursion case
template <typename C, typename K0, typename ... Ks>
auto Find (C const & cnt, K0 && key0, Ks && ... keys)
 {
   auto mapIt = cnt.find(std::forward<K0>(key0));

   return mapIt == cnt.cend()
      ? nullptr
      : Find(mapIt->second, std::forward<Ks>(keys)...);
 }
```

For C++11, the recursion case require also the trailing return type; by example

```
-> decltype(Find(cnt.find(std::forward<K0>(key0))->second, std::forward<Ks>(keys)...))
```